# Is there any advantage in minifying nodejs server side code?

Tags: javascript, node.js, minify

Is there any advantage in minifying nodejs code the same way one minifies javascript (for size / network donwload speed mainly). I know that for nodejs once a file is `required` it is loaded into V8 and the contents are processed and kept in memory in a form or another, most probably not in the same state it was read.

Given this, would minifying nodejs code lead to faster module loading, module installation (for big projects npm can take quite a lot to complete) or any other advantage? I know there are drawbacks, mainly not being able to proper debug the code with a normal IDE debugger.

Comment: Probably related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11805291/does-minifying-impact-performance-of-node-js

Comment: thanks, did not find this question when I searched prior to posting :)

Answer (score -1):

There are more disadvantages than advantages.

The few advantages which do not have much impact are when Node runs your code it will have less characters to parse and you will save only a small portion of disk.

But when it comes to the point of deployment and debuging you will end up having and extra step on work flow and looking through some uglyfied/minified code would be a nightmare.